Exif write data to image metadata using native_exif giving exceptioin
This is my permissions file:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
</manifest>

I have added this:
        <activity
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"


Getting this error:
E/DartMessenger(19487): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20241024-WA0005.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

When I try writing exif data of file.
Here is my code:
    if (imagePath.isNotEmpty && tags.isNotEmpty) {
      List<String> tagList = tags.split(',').map((tag) => tag.trim()).toList();
      print("Adding tags to $imagePath: $tagList");
      exif = await Exif.fromPath(imagePath);

      try {
        await exif!.writeAttribute('UserComment', tagList.join(','));
        print("Tags written to EXIF metadata for $imagePath");
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error writing tags to EXIF metadata: $e");
      } finally {
        await exif!.close(); 
      }
    }
  }

Maybe I am overlooking something. Its been hours and I am unable to figure out. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.
